# Qt/GCC: Returning an object/nullptr from a function by value. Why does this code compile?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

The following code does not compile with GCC 4.8:

```
SomeClass makeObject(bool returnsNullptr)
{
    if (!returnsNullptr)
    {
        return SomeClass();
    }
    else
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
C:\Users\HGH\Documents\GitHub\PureCpp\ReturnValueOptimization\src\main.cpp:64: error: could not convert 'nullptr' from 'std::nullptr_t' to 'SomeClass'
         return nullptr;
                ^
```

As I am returning an object by value this is expected. But the following Qt code compiles and appears to run just fine. Why is that so?

```
QByteArray ResourceFileManager::loadFromFolder(const QString& folderPath, const QString& fileName)
{
    QString fullFilePath = folderPath + "/" + fileName;
    QFile file(fullFilePath);
    qDebug() << "Loading resource: " + file.fileName();

    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {

        QByteArray buffer = file.readAll();
        file.close();

        return buffer;
    }
    else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Answer (score 4):

One of `QByteArray`s [constructors takes a pointer](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbytearray.html#QByteArray-2), so one is being constructed for you.  Presumably if your `SomeClass` type had a constructor with a pointer arg, it would behave the same.

Comment: This is correct. I added SomeClass(const SomeClass*){} and it compiles but why does it work now? This I fail to understand.

Comment: `nullptr` is essentially equal to `0` which is a perfectly acceptable pointer value.  As your constructor is not marked `explicit` and has single pointer arg, the compiler will implicitly construct a `SomeClass` instance on the stack for you using `nullptr` as the input value.

Comment: @Zingam Implicit conversion. The same reason you can do `std::string s() { return "hello"; }`.

Comment: Is implicit conversion the reason why "if (nullptr == buffer)", where "buffer" is the returned object (QByteArray(nullptr)) by loadFromFolder(...)) -> QByteArray buffer = loadFromFolder(...);?

Comment: Not in that case as `QByteArray` has an equality operator (https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbytearray.html#operator-eq-eq-92) that can accepts a pointer.  Here is an excellent write up of how C++ handles implicit conversion: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast

Comment: @cmannett85 I see. Thank you. But I am still unsure if that is a valid comparison in the case of QByteArray: if (nullptr == buffer). True understanding still eludes me. I think it should be a valid one but is it really?

Comment: The only reason the equality operator I linked to wouldn't be called is if `nullptr` couldn't represent a `const char*` - which is not true.

Comment: A glance at the source code helped me understand that. Thank you!